# Zabbix monitoring in hybrid environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, zabbix, network-monitoring

I would like to use Zabbix to monitor our data center and AWS infrastructure environment. Most of the servers in AWS and data centers are behind NAT inside private subnets. Is it possible to use same Zabbix server to monitor both environment? What would be the best practice of secure monitoring the hosts in this kind of hybrid environment where AWS and Data Center are not linked?

Answer (score 0):

Site to site VPN between datacenter and AWS VPC seems like the best option. Then it wouldnt matter where your Zabbix server was.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html